# Rails - Signup code validity check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So, I'm new at this and trying to learn by jumping right in.

I have a slightly odd login in my rails app that works like this:

- Admins generate a code and specify an upper limit
- Users log in by entering this code and some details which are saved

Models:

```
class Code < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessible :code, :maxusers
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :code
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :code_id
end
```

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to "/welcome"
    end
  end
end
```

So for example the code is 123456 with a limit of 5

The first 5 users can sign up with their Name, Email and 123456

So the question is: How do I check that the code is valid before saving? It must exist and have less than 5 users already assigned.

It seems really simple but I can't figure out the syntax, I was playing with a before_filter in the controller or before save in the model but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`before_filter` is a bad idea: models have to bothered about their integrity, not controllers.

You can try *something like*:

```
# in your respective model

validate :at_least_five_codes

def at_least_five_codes
  errors.add(:base, 'Try another code') unless User.where(code: code).count < 5
end
```

And you'll be unable to save your model if current code was used for 5 times.

Comment: Thanks, I like that, I'll try that out and let you know. That doesn't check if the code exists first in the Code table though, can I check that at the same time from the User model; like `if defined? Code.find_by_code(:code)` or something?

Comment: @Jamie Yeah, you can do it via `exists?`: `if Code.exists?(code: '12345')`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F